# How to fix 'undefined' values in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to pass a parameter to my route but as it reaches to my store `action`, it gives me `undefined` error!

I have tried changing my parameter name as well as I also tried to put the `$route.params.id` in a method and called it from there but still no effect!

[As shown by vue-dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GONHM.png)

#### Breakfast.vue

```
<router-link to="/menu/add/1" tag="h2" class="pull-right">Add Menu</router-link>
```

#### MenuAdd.vue

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions(['addMenu']),
  addMenuItem() {
    this.addMenu(this.menu, this.$route.params.typeId);
  }
}
```

#### router.js

```
{ path: '/menu/add/:typeId', component: MenuAdd }
```

#### state

```
state: {
    menu: [],
    breakfastMenu: [],
    lunchMenu: [],
    dinnerMenu: []
  }
```

#### action

```
addMenu: ({ commit }, { name, price, description }, typeId) => {
  commit('ADD_MENU', { name, price, description }, typeId);
  alert('Menu Successfully Added');
}
```

#### mutation

```
'ADD_MENU': (state, { name, price, description }, typeId) => {
   state.menu.forEach((element) => {
     if (element.id == state.menu.length) {
       state.menu.push({
        id: element.id + 1,
        name: name,
        price: price,
        categoryId: typeId,
        description: description
       })
     }
   })
  }
}
```

I want my `typeId` to work and send my parameter to the `store.js` so that I can get my specified result

Comment: Have you called the `addMenuItem()` method in `created` hook ?

Comment: No, actually the method addMenuItem() gets called only when the user wants to add a menu item.

Whereas, I have put updateMenu() method in created() hook which calls the getter method getBreakfastMenu() which filters menu items in menuData.js that belong in breakfast!

Answer (score 5):

You can only pass a single payload to a Vuex action.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#dispatch

This line is trying to pass two payloads:

```js
this.addMenu(this.menu, this.$route.params.typeId);
```

The second argument will be treated as the `options` for `dispatch`. That's used for setting `root: true`, which isn't relevant here. Effectively the `typeId` is just being thrown away.

You'll need to wrap the two arguments into a single payload object:

```js
this.addMenu({ menu: this.menu, typeId: this.$route.params.typeId });
```

In the action you could then pull this apart using something like:

```js
addMenu: ({ commit }, { menu: { name, price, description }, typeId }) => {
```

Personally that's a bit too much argument destructuring for my taste, I'd probably move it into the method body instead.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the answer! I was wondering about what you said about 'destructuring', I am still not clear about it. Can you be brief and explain more?

Comment: @extboy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment Personally I would write `{ menu: { name, price, description }, typeId }` as `{ menu, typeId }` and then have `const { name, price, description } = menu` in the method body.